# What are the keymappings for the LibreOffice AutoCorrect "Accept with"?

Tags: icons, gui, libreoffice-writer

LibreOffice has a pretty limited method of assigning the key to accept autocorrections, I know what three of the five options are, but have no idea what the other two options represent.

- LibreOffice Writer

  - "Tools" menu

    - "AutoCorrect Options..." submenu option

      - "Word Completion" tab

        - "Accept With" drop-down options:

```
↘ - ? ________ ?
↩ - enter/return
‿ - space bar
➞ - ? ________ ?
⇥ - tab
```

What keys do the southeast arrow (↘) and the rightwards arrow (➞) represent?

Answer (score 0):

In LibreOffice v4.0 on a MacBook keyboard under OSX 10.7.5, the mappings correlate to:

- southeast arrow icon = I expected it to be the end key, but the common key combination of fn + right_arrow is not working; perhaps a bug
- rightwards arrow icon = right arrow key

I'll do more research on this and update if I notice a change.